# Can someone explain what hunzip is for?

Tags: compression, utilities, spell-checking, hunspell

I understand what `hunspell` is for, but I was browsing the source code and the `man`, and I'm not sure:

Does `hunzip` compress text files or just dictionaries ?

Answer (score 2):

`hunzip` is a decompression tool.  For compression you want to look at `hzip`.
Both will operate on text files, but they are optimized for working with sorted dictionaries and word lists.